# SQL Server 2008 database Backup

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, database

today I was trying to restore a database with a backup I had made previously on another computer, however I kept getting the following error message:

```
the media loaded on "filepath" is formatted to support 2 media families, but 1 media families are expected according to the device specification
```

I didn't look into it at the time, I just figured it was a bad backup and I'd redo it when I got home. So now I'm trying to do another backup, and I'm getting the above error message for that too.

I did backup to a different location at one point, however that no longer exists now. Is there a way i can get passed this error and just do a fresh backup of the database?

any pointers would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expecting two seperate files to fulfil the backup set, and you've only supplied one. One was possible the database backup file and the other one maybe a transaction log?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I actually managed to dig out the other backup file, two .bak files. I'm not sure how that happened but I should be able to restore the database now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the backup to a new file.  The existing file is configured so that you split the backup across two backup files.  You may as well delete the file if you don't have the other file, as the backups which are contained within the file are useless as half of the backup information is missing.